# JavaScript to detect what checkboxes and checked and perform action

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, checkbox

I have a jsp page with a checkbox declared like so

```
<form:checkbox path="affProgramSessionList[${status.index}].programSessionDetailId" id="checkbox_${session.id}" data-id="${session.id}" value="${session.id}" />
```

it is contained within a for loop and basically a checkbox is displayed for each session.  That all works fine and I have no issues.

currently when a check box is checked this function is ran

```
$("input[id*='checkbox_']").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function(){
        var dataid = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var divId = "fullAttendence_" + dataid;
        var divIdAttendee = "attendeeType_" + dataid;

        $('#' + divId).toggle(this.checked);
        $('#' + divIdAttendee).toggle(this.checked);
    });

});
```

This then results in some other checkboxes being checked and some divs that were hidden being shown.

I am now adding in functionality for if someone had checked some check boxes and saved and comes back to the page then those check boxes will be checked.

I have that part working but I can't get the function to run properly.

I have the following

```
if ($("input[id*='checkbox_']").is(':checked')) {

    var dataid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var divId = "fullAttendence_" + dataid;
    var divIdAttendee = "attendeeType_" + dataid;

    $('#' + divId).toggle(this.checked);
    $('#' + divIdAttendee).toggle(this.checked);
}
```

This function DOES get called as I tested it with a console.log.

the issue is that

```
var dataid = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

comes back as

```
undefined
```

Now my assumption right now is just that my new function to check for checked boxes and the other function that gets call are not working quite the same and my function doesn't know which check box was checked just that at least one was?

any help is really appreciated.

Comment: As you are using jQuery anway, don't accessthe Datastore via `attr('data-id')`, but use `.data('id')` to get and set values. Just as a "best practice" suggestion.

Comment: If that change is made does ' data-id="${session.id}" ' still get placed into the checkbox deceleration or would it be done differently?

Comment: On the markup-side, you can and should still use `data-foo="bar"`, just accessing and changing it via jQuery should become `$(elem).data('foo'); // returns 'bar'` and `$(elem).data('foo', 'quuuux'); // is now 'quuuux'`, respectively

Comment: awesome, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($("input[id*='checkbox_']").is(':checked')) {
```

... will filter out the first checked input and operate on that. If you want to iterate on all checkboxes, use this construct:

```
$("input[id*='checkbox_']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // do something
    }
});
```